# Feathers.js event filtering method not fired

Tags: javascript, socket.io, feathersjs

I have created a `feathers service` which accepts locationRequests. And as the [documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/real-time/events.html#created) states, each time the `create` endpoint of the service method is invoked an `event` is emitted.

I can subscribe to this event like this.

```
locationRequestService.on('created',(locationRequest) => {
    console.log(locationRequest);
});
```

And as stated I can log the newly creatd `locationRequest` object each time a `create` method is invoked.

And following along I should be able to restrict the flow of the this event using `event filters` as mentioned [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/real-time/filtering.html#registering-filters).

```
locationRequestService.filter(function(data, connection){
    if(connection.userId != data.userId) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

But the problem is that this method is never invoked.

I am sure I am missing something obvious. Please help me out.

Comment: Are you listening to the event on the client or the server?

Comment: I am gonna listen using the socket.io library for android.

Comment: You have to authenticate the socket in order to set the user it on the socket (https://docs.feathersjs.com/authentication/readme.html#authentication-over-sockets) so that it can be filtered.

Comment: actually the problem is not with authentication at all. At least when I place a break point on the if block it should be invoked isn't it?